# How to insert array data into chart of ng2-google-chart in angular 7

Tags: angular, api, google-visualization

I use an angular development environment 7
And I'm trying to run a pie chart of ng2 google chart
Via API - and angular service.

Attached is a picture of my TS file

Question: How do I enter the values ​​that come from my array to the DataTable of the chart?

Thanks

````
constructor(private _getIncomeService: getIncomeService) { }
    _GetAveragesModel: GetAveragesModel[];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.fnGetAverages();
    }
    fnGetAverages() {
        this._getIncomeService.GetAverages(279).subscribe(x => {
            this._GetAveragesModel = x;
        });
    }       
    public pieChart = {
        chartType: 'PieChart',
        dataTable: [
            ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
            ['ss', 11],
            ['Eat', 2],
            ['Commute', 2],
            ['Watch TV', 2],
            ['Sleep', 7]
        ],
        options: {
            title: 'Tasks',
            slices: {
                0: { offset: 0.3 },
                1: { offset: 0.2 },
            },
            width: '100%', height: '100%',
            is3D: true,
            chartArea: {left: "3%",top: "3%",height: "94%",width: "94%"}
        }
    };
```[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RMwk.png
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use ng2-google-chart, instead use **angular-google-charts** (npm i angular-google-charts).

this is the HTML code
You have a tag like [data] and Value "dataichange" => this value you can change the name in ts file

```
<google-chart #chart
   [title]="title"
   [type]="type"
   [data]="dataichange"
   [columnNames]="columnNames"
   [options]="options"
   [width]="width"
   [height]="height">
</google-chart>
```

this is the .ts file with data hardcoded

```js
title = 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014';
   type = 'PieChart';
   dataichange = [
      ['Firefox', 45.0],
      ['IE', 26.8],
      ['Chrome', 12.8],
      ['Safari', 8.5],
      ['Opera', 6.2],
      ['Others', 0.7] 
   ];
   columnNames = ['Browser', 'Percentage'];
   options = {    
   };
   width = 550;
   height = 400;
```

**To solve your issue -  replace the data with your own New Array.**

**You need a new array because the array that come from service is too big.**

**So you need to create a new array just for the columns to need for a specific chart.**

**To do that I used "map" to get the array columns and "push" to create them in the new array with the order I set.**

```js
Datachart: any[];
 fnGetAverages() {
  this._getIncomeService.GetAverages(279).subscribe(Res => {
   this._GetAveragesModel = Res;
   Res.map(item => {
    this.Datachart.push([item.OrderTypeName, item.AveragePerDiner]);
   })
  });
 }
```

and now replace in HTML the [data]="Datachart" 
the DataChart is your filtered new array

```html
<google-chart #chart
   [title]="title"
   [type]="type"
   [data]="Datachart" // Here I changed to the new array name "Datachart"
   [columnNames]="columnNames"
   [options]="options"
   [width]="width"
   [height]="height">
</google-chart>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

this is work 4 me. **this is a good solution**

Answer (score 1):

Map the dataTable property to _GetAveragesModel and use pieChart as getter. If it changes the value of the pie chart property will also change.

```
get pieChart():any {
    return {
      chartType: 'PieChart',
      dataTable: this.__GetAveragesModel.map(e => {
  if (e.hasOwnProperty('OrderTypeName') && e.hasOwnProperty('AveragePerDinner')) {
    return [e.OrderTypeName,e.AveragePerDinner]
  }
      }),
      options: {
            title: 'Tasks',
            slices: {
                0: { offset: 0.3 },
                1: { offset: 0.2 },
            },
            width: '100%', height: '100%',
            is3D: true,
            chartArea: {left: "3%",top: "3%",height: "94%",width: "94%"}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You,
I have tried your code, it looks like its getting the data, BUT,
the code is looping now, and the page is stuck.

When I debugged it, the code looping to the "if" statement and getting the data again and again.

Do you have any idea how to stop the loop?

Thanks

Comment: and i'm getting an error in console: 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Can you try changing the code to below:

`dataTable: this._GetAveragesModel ? this._GetAveragesModel.map(e => {
        return e ? [e.OrderTypeName, e.AveragePerDinner] : null;
      }).filter(d => d !== null):[]`

This should work. You are getting error because initially your value for the variable is set to undefined.

Comment: this code **"get pieChart():any {return {  "** It creates the sticking problem.... Even when I'm trying to put the table manually It still got stuck.. So all the code you suggested to me isn't work with google chart